# How to put database connection check validation in Unix shell script

Tags: sql, unix

I have created shell script for connection database.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Declaring a variable used in this program
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Databasename="XYZ"
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ************************** MAIN PROGRAM STARTS ******************************************
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cd $SCRIPT_PATH

db2 connect to $Databasename

touch $UserId $RoleName $MCD_Prod

echo "UserId" > $UserId

echo "RoleName" > $RoleName

db2 -x "Select A.USER_ID from USER A ,ROLE_TYPE R, USER_ROLE U where A.USER_ID=U.USER_ID AND U.ROLE_ID=R.ROLE_ID" >> $UserId

db2 -x "Select R.ROLE_NM from USER A ,ROLE_TYPE R, USER_ROLE U where A.USER_ID=U.USER_ID AND U.ROLE_ID=R.ROLE_ID order by A.USER_ID" >> $RoleName
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have made database validation when i select * in database an connection not found.

But if the database name is incorrrect from "XYZ" to "XYZ1" , database could not connect but program terminate here only..

I need to put validation ..Please help

Comment: Is their is any way in shell script where i can check ..is database is connected succufully or not and determinate program here only if not connected

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the following code ...

```
if ! db2 -x "Select A.USER_ID from USER A ,ROLE_TYPE R, USER_ROLE U where A.USER_ID=U.USER_ID AND U.ROLE_ID=R.ROLE_ID" >> $UserId
then
  echo "there was an error, maybe the connection failed
fi
```